# Can't connect to Oracle database in Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, oracle

I'm trying to connect to oracle database but I get this error

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string ordb = "Data Source =orcl  ;User Id = hr ; password =hr;";
        OracleConnection conn;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new OracleConnection(ordb);
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your dll references, your app seems to be an X64 base, but maybe one of the dll's is of a different format